# getting a segmentation fault with pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I am currently struggling with a Segmentation fault.

I have a function which takes a some arguments and inserts them into elements of a struct and then creates a thread with `pthread_create`. This struct is then used in the struct function to assign values to variables. The code that does the above looks like this:

```
void create_monsters(int monster_id, unsigned char x_coord, unsigned char y_coord,
              unsigned char monster_type )
{
    properties *prop;
    prop = (properties*)malloc(sizeof (properties)); 

   prop->x_coord = x_coord;
   prop->y_coord = y_coord;
   prop->monster_type = monster_type;
 
   pthread_create(&monster_tid[monster_id], NULL, monster, &prop);

 }
```

The thread function looks like this:

```
void *monsters(void* props)
{

 properties *pptr = (properties *) props;

 unsigned char x_coord = pptr->x_coord;
 unsigned char y_coord = pptr->y_coord;
 unsigned char monstor_type = pptr->monster_type;
 ...
```

after this, only the above unsigned char variables are used.

I had also tried

```
 properties prop;
   p.x_coord = x_coord;
   p.y_coord = y_coord;
   p.monster_type = monster_type;
```

instead of the approach with `malloc` and nothing works, I always get a segmentation fault and I do not understand why and I do not know how to fix it.

I had been given the advice to use deep copy, but I thought I used that with malloc.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [this Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Improve your question to make it some [mre]

Answer (score 2):

Pass `prop`, which is *already a pointer* (`P*`), not `&prop` (`P**`):

```
P* prop = mallocIsFine();
pthread_create(.., NULL, monster, prop);
```

The thread function is incorrectly attempting to access a `P**` as a `P*` in the original code:

```
P *pptr = (P *) props; // props refers to a P**, oops!
```

Answer (score 2):

`prop` is a local variable in `create_monsters`, and its value is a pointer to a newly allocated `properties` object.

You want to pass the pointer value that is stored *in* `prop`. Don't pass a pointer *to* `prop`.  Just do this:

```
pthread_create(&monster_tid[monster_id], NULL, monster, prop);
```

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault may come from this:

```
properties *prop;
...     
pthread_create(&monster_tid[monster_id], NULL, monster, &prop);
```

As prop already is a pointer to a properties structure, using the & operator, you are getting a pointer to a pointer of a structure. But in the monster function you expect a properties*, or a pointer to a properties struct. Call pthread_create function with the following arguments:

```
pthread_create(monster_tid[monster_id], NULL, monster, prop);
```

Looks like you could be making the same mistake in &monster_tid[monster_id]. As you didn't show monster_tid declaration you should check it's type to make a proper declaration.